# What is the syntax of this line $_POST ? '' : $_POST = ...something;?

Tags: if-statement, post, syntax, global-variables, global

I tried to understand it by simplifying but it did make a difference

```
  $apple = 'almwWa';
  $banana = 'bababa';
  $apple ? '' : $apple = 'dsadsad';
  echo $apple;
```

What does this do? `? '' :`

The original code is this:

`$_POST ? '' : $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);`
Which I undestand except for the first part

Comment: Read up on [**ternary operator**](https://davidwalsh.name/php-shorthand-if-else-ternary-operators) in PHP or as a matter of fact, in any language.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a ternary operator (cf. http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php)

If the first part isn't false, the second part will be return else the 3rd part will be returned.

```
echo (true)  ? "yes" : "no";    //prints yes
echo (false) ? "yes" : "no";    //prints no
```